# How do I compute a confidence level for a forced ranking survey?

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, ranking

How do I compute a confidence level for a forced ranking survey?  For example, say I have 10 categories, each with four associated statements that must be ranked either 1, 2, 3 or 4 with no duplicate ranking within the category (forced ranking).  Say I get fifty responses.  How do I compute the confidence level/margin of error?

Comment: welcome to the website. Confidence level/margin of error for which statistic? As far as I understand, your concern is lack of independence between the categories: if the R selected 1 for the first option, then the others would have to be taken from $\{2, 3, 4\}$.

Comment: The categories are completely independent.  Each category has four associated statements to be ranked 1, 2, 3 or 4 without duplicates within the category.  This isn't an academic exercise, by the way.  My small town of Manitou Springs has developed a vision document for the city and we are considering sending out a survey to prioritize the resulting statements.  Thanks very much for your interest and help.

Comment: Just realized I didn't directly answer your question directly.  Yes, if R selected 1 then the remaining selections would come from {2,3,4}, etc.  Confidence level would be calculated for the responses in each individual category.  For example, if we have 50 responses and a four selection forced ranking for each of the ten independent categories how do we calculate confidence and margin of error for the results in each in individual category.  With four statements there are 24 permutations for each category.  This seems similar to a Lickertt scale for each category with a scale from 1 to 24.

Comment: Likert scales are ordinal, and 24 permutations are nominal (no ordering between them). I am sure you can get the statistics like the # or proportion of people who prefer alternative 1 to alternative 2 (by identifying the 12 permutations that rank them that way), for all pairwise comparisons. Or you can do the proportion of people who ranked alternative 1 as the best one (6 permutations). Either of these would admit a CI on a proportion in a regular manner. But as far as ways to present the four alternatives in a single summary statistics or a table - I am not aware of a good method to do this.

Comment: StasK - Thank you.  As far as reporting goes, I think a simple average rating for each statement in each category will suffice.  As far as the CI goes, what do you mean by "[calculate] CI on a proportion in a regular manner" (sorry, I'm a rank amature, pardon the pun).  I get the point about why a Likert won't work and understand your point about 6 permutations per rank.  Can you point me to something more specific about doing a CI on a proportion?  I appreciate your taking the time for this.  Tim